# Ideas on how to make multiple selectable resizeable boxes in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to develop a web application that can take an image and draw multiple, resizeable boxes on the image.  I have been looking into a lot of cropping plugins, but i cant seem to find what I am looking for.  I just need to be able to draw multiple boxes on an image and return coordinates.  I am looking for a plugin that would be easily modified for this or if anyone could give me any idea on how I could get started on this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the [Image Annotation Plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-image-annotate/) for 1.3.X? Example [here](http://blog.flipbit.co.uk/2009/03/jquery-image-annotation-plugin.html).

Comment: Sure thing, from the description it sounded like you were looking for an image tagging library.  Glad I could help.